# Unity UI Text Selected while the scene loads

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need a way to have a UI Text already selected at the beginning of the scene, so that I can type into it through the keyboard as soon as the game starts. There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base class `Selectable` to refer to your ui element to make this a bit more generic.  This works for all UI Components that inherit Selectable, which includes InputField, Button, and others.

```
public UnityEngine.UI.Selectable uiElement;

void Start()
{
    uiElement.Select();
}
```

You can also refer to the specific ui element, same method applies.

```
public UnityEngine.UI.InputField inputField;

void Start()
{
    inputField.Select();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this at start event..

```
EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(inputField.gameObject);
```